# Unsetting an enum flag

Tags: c#

Consider

```
   [Flags]
   public enum State
   {
      IsCool = 0x1,
      SomethingElse = 0x2
   }
```

I have a `State someState` and if some expression evaluates to true, I want to unset the `IsCool` flag of `someState` *regardless* of it being already set or unset. This means that I can't really use `someState ^= State.IsCool` but what can I use instead?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You need to approach this the reverse way than when setting a flag: bitwise AND the current state with the complement of the flag you want to remove.

```
someState &= ~State.IsCool;
```

Comment: I used XOR (conditionally) for the longest time, until I sat down, wrote out some truth tables and discovered the AND NOT approach. So much easier!

Comment: Interestingly, the Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types) get it wrong - they say
    // Remove a flag using bitwise XOR.
    meetingDays = meetingDays ^ Days.Tuesday;